# ScalaJS: What's the state of the art for cross-platform dates?

Tags: scala.js

I'm using ScalaJS with Play.  Many of the models I'd like to use on both JS and JVM platforms involve dates and times.  Given the lack of a cross-platform date/time library, how are people approaching this?

Things I know about:

1. scalajs-java-time project (https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-java-time) to port JDK8's java.time api to Scala.js.  Unfortunately, it's far from complete and judging by the commit logs, seems to have stalled.
2. https://github.com/mdedetrich/soda-time is a port of JodaTime to Scala/Scala.js.  But it's not ready for production use.
3. An old post at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-js/6JoJ7x-VxLA suggests storing milliseconds in shared code and then doing implicit conversions on each platform to either js.Date or JodaTime.  But we really need a common interface, which this doesn't give.
4. Li Haoyi's excellent "Hands-on Scala.js" has a simple cross-platform library (http://www.lihaoyi.com/hands-on-scala-js/#ASimpleCross-BuiltLibrary) that could, in theory, be extended to come up with an API in /shared that delegates to JodaTime on the jvm and Momento on js -- but that sounds like a lot of work.
5. (added later) https://github.com/soc/scala-java-time is based on an implementation of java-time that was contributed to OpenJDK.  The README claims that most stuff is working.  Right now, this looks like the most promising approach for my needs.

Any advice from those who have gone before me?  Right now the fourth options seems like my best bet (with the API limited to stuff I actually use).  I'm hoping for something better.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://pavkin.ru/cross-platform-polymorphic-datetime-values-in-scala-with-type-classes/

Comment: Yes, that reference is helpful.  Will report back more extensively after I've actually tried it out.  Thank you.

Comment: I found the pavkin.ru reference to be a really complex solution that appears to have different coding conventions on JVM as opposed to JS.  I wasn't able to make good headway.  Also don't like the idea of needing to parameterize all of my case classes with the Date/Time stuff.  Perhaps I'm just not understanding things, but I don't think I'll be going down this road.

Comment: Just googled "scala java-time" to locate the work cited in (1), above.  It returned a github project that I haven't seen before today -- https://github.com/soc/scala-java-time.  The README claims it's based on code that was contributed to OpenJDK and thus has licenses that allow it to be translated/adapted/whatever to scala.  Also claims to have made good progress with most stuff working.

Comment: The scala-java-time project cited above appears to be stalled but a fork at https://github.com/cquiroz/scala-java-time has had lots of work.  That's what I'm going with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was in the same boat as you, and the best solution I came up with was [cquiroz's scala-java-time library](https://github.com/cquiroz/scala-java-time). From reading the comments to your question above, it appears you landed at the same place eventually!

I came here from a google search, and given how much better this solution is than the alternatives you mentions above, let's consider marking this question as resolved for future visitors.

Comment: +1 for cquiroz's implement of scala-java-time.  See my last note as of May 17, 2017 :)

And yes, I'll check this as answered.